# How to display server side error message on the UI

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error-messages

I have apex class with custom error message and if there is any error occurred then I would like to show to the user on the UI.

Apex class code //snippet

```
     try {
         //some awesome code          
     } catch(Exception e){ 
        AuraHandledException ex = new AuraHandledException('');
        system.debug('error: ' + e.getMessage()); //I can see the error in the system.debug log.
        ex.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        throw ex;
     }
```

But on the Aura Component the error message is getting swallowed

```
     .....
     else if (state === "ERROR") {              
            var errors = response.getError();  
            if(errors){
                if(errors.message){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(errors.message)); 
                }
                else{
                    alert('nothing to show);
                }    
            }
        }
```

I'm getting `errors.message` empty string but I know that apex is throwing an error message but somehow it's getting swallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be not the best way to do it. But I used to have an Apex wrapper for this purpose, and handle the error in Apex try-catch and then use it in front-end as needed.

E.g.
**Apex class**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static CmpDataWrapper saveData(String valTest) {
    CmpDataWrapper idw = new CmpDataWrapper();
    
    try{
        // Do stuff 
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      idw.hasError = true; 
      idw.message = ex.getLineNumber() +' - '+ex.getMessage();
      System.debug(idw);
    }
    
    return idw;
}

    // Component data wrapper to keep all data records, settings, config retrieved from Backend
    public class CmpDataWrapper{
        /**
        * @description List of Contact Wrappers
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<ConWrapper> listConW{get;set;}
        
        /**
        * @description User message (if any)
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public String message{get;set;}
        
        /**
        * @description if object has any errors
        */
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean hasError{get;set;}
    }
```

**Aura Helper:**

```
saveData: function (component, event) {

    let action = component.get('c.saveData');
    
    action.setParams({
        'valTest' : component.get('v.valTest'),
    });
    
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){            
        
        let state = response.getState();
        
        //Success
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            let ret = response.getReturnValue();

            if (ret.hasError==true)
                helper.showMessage2User(component, helper, $A.get("$Label.c.Error"), ret.message,'error','sticky');
            else{
                component.set('v.showModal', false);                     
                helper.showMessage2User(component, helper, $A.get("$Label.c.Success"),ret.message ,'success','');
            }

            //Unknown Error
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            helper.showMessage2User(component, helper, $A.get("$Label.c.Error"), errors[0].message,'error','sticky');
        }
        
    });
    
    $A.enqueueAction(action); // Run the action
},



showMessage2User: function(component, helper, title, message, type, mode){
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    if(toastEvent){
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": title,
            "message": message,
            "type": type,
            "mode": mode
        });
        
        toastEvent.fire();
    } else {
        alert(message);
    }  
},
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `errors[0].message`. Despite the singular term get*Error*(), it actually returns a list of errors. See the example in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm).

```
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
```

Also note that, apparently, there may be an error state without errors, but this is abnormal in my experience.